# collection object displaying only key

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a collection and added some values to it. Now how can I display both key and value for the items.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim CollDay As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CollDay.Add(1, "sunday")
        CollDay.Add(2, "monday")
        CollDay.Add(3, "tuesday")
        CollDay.Add(4, "wednesday")

        For Each CollDay_ In CollDay
            MessageBox.Show(CollDay_)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Message box is only displaying key, how can I print the message like: "1 - sunday", "2 - monday"

Comment: Why are you using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`?

Comment: I don't know I just copied from tutorial. I am new to VB.NET.

Comment: The help page for `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` says: "Whenever possible, you should use the generic collections in the System.Collections.Generic namespace or the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace instead of a Visual Basic Collection."

Comment: With the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` the `.Add` method has the value followed by the key. So, "sunday", in your code is the key and `1` is the value.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Maybe we can suggest the right kind of collection to use?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am just trying to write a code using collection class having add and display items.

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` is really only suitable for porting pre-.NET VB, where it duplicates the functionality of the classic VB `Collection`.  Those collections were fine for their time, but they don't really make sense in modern VB.  They don't use generics (so you get `Object` back out and must cast to get the correct type) and the keying is a little weird too because the classic VB `Collection` acts like both a `List(Of T)` and a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent of what you've do so far, using the more modern dictionary collection:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
    Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    
    dictionary.Add("sunday", 1)
    dictionary.Add("monday", 2)
    dictionary.Add("tuesday", 3)
    dictionary.Add("wednesday", 4)

    For Each item In dictionary
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Value, item.Key))
    Next

End Sub
```

I expect that you've transposed the idea of a key and and value and maybe this is what you actually need:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
    Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    
    dictionary.Add(1, "sunday")
    dictionary.Add(2, "monday")
    dictionary.Add(3, "tuesday")
    dictionary.Add(4, "wednesday")

    For Each item In dictionary
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Key, item.Value))
    Next

End Sub
```

Finally, a better version might be this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    
    list.Add("sunday")
    list.Add("monday")
    list.Add("tuesday")
    list.Add("wednesday")

    For i = 0 To list.Count - 1
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} - {1}", i + 1, list(i)))
    Next

End Sub
```